# How to update or delete a record from cursor manually

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-cursor

How I can delete a record from cursor manually ?

I do not want select query agian !!

For example:

```
 holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cursor.manuallyUpdate(ID, NewValue); // Something like this
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
 });
```

Please help me,

Thanks

Comment: Can you add more information? Are you using a ContentProvider or just a database? What do you mean you don't want to select query *again*?

Comment: You can't delete `row` inside `cursor`, `cursor` holds records from database so you need to delete it from database and `query` a new `cursor`. Or you can check value of item from `cursor` and skip to show it on your layout.

Comment: @McAdam331 I use custom cursor adapter, i don't want use swapCursor or changeCursor for update ListView.

Comment: If you want to update ListView, you definitely use swapCursor().

Comment: Cursor provide no such method, u may try to use List as a data holder for the adapter.